# Do we need to enable G++ on RHEL 6.1

Tags: rhel, gcc, g++

I have RHEL6.1 but I can't compile using `g++`, when I execute `g++`, I get the below :

```
-bash: g++: command not found
```

so I assume I don't have g++ but I do have gcc installed. When I run `gcc -v`.

I get :

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix
```

Please suggest. Do I need to install `g++` separately or is it already installed and I have to enable it from somewhere.

EDIT :
On running : yum install gcc-c++ I get the below output

---

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package gcc-c++ available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Could you also include the output of `yum provides '*bin/g++'`?

Answer (score 2):

> or is it already installed

Looks like it is not; if it were `g++` would be available.  Try:

```
yum search ++ | grep ^g
```

The package is likely called `gcc-c++`, but this should catch it just in case it is, e.g., just `g++`.  *Do not* use one of the packages with "cross" in the description (e.g., "Cross-build binary for ....").

Answer (score 2):

```
# yum provides '*bin/g++'
...
gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.i686 : C++ support for GCC
Repo        : sl
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/g++
```

tells us that the **gcc-c++** package has `g++`, so you'll need to run:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `command-not-found` to search for the package of g++ and how to install it. On my debian machine, I get this result:

```
$ command-not-found g++
The program 'g++' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install g++
tcsh: command not found
$
```

So, on my computer, `g++` is in the package g++ and not in the package gcc.